# При переносе сайта Laravel с openserver на хостинг столкнулся с проблемой:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.7

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'theukrai_user'@'ip-adress' to database 'theukrai_base' (SQL: select * from `category` order by `created_at` asc)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой .env файл

Comment: А вам провайдер все данные по БД выдал?

Comment: Если это продакшен .env, то вас не смущает, что host-базы не указан и app_url такой?

Comment: db_host указал в виде ip адреса, app_url - виде силки на сайт. Но дальше выдает эту ошибку.